# Connect to Ignite Cluster over SSL using JDBC Thin Client

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, ignite, gridgain

Though, I've setup SSL between all Ignite Nodes and whole Ignite Cluster is secured, I'm able to access the data through JDBC thin client without passing any SSL configs. Does it mean though the cluster is secured we can connect without passing any ssl config/cert?

I want no one can connect to the Ignite Cluster until and unless required ssl certs provided, is that possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need explicitly enable SSL for thin protocols:

https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/thin-clients/getting-started-with-thin-clients#enabling-ssltls-for-thin-clients

```
<property name="clientConnectorConfiguration">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.ClientConnectorConfiguration">
        <property name="sslEnabled" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</property>
```

Comment: You also need to enable SSL for `ConnectorConfiguration` and REST (if used) to have all bases covered.

Comment: @Michael After adding below property, when trying to access JDBC thin client getting the following error                                                                                            Error: Failed to connect to Ignite cluster [url=jdbc:ignite:thin://node1.example.com:10800/PUBLIC] (state=08001,code=0)   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to read incoming message (not enough data).

Comment: @sandipbhowmik it means that now SSL is enabled and you need to provide ssl sertificate to you jdbc client in connection string like this:
"jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1/?sslMode=require" +
                "&sslClientCertificateKeyStoreUrl=" + "path/to/certifficate.jks" +
                        "&sslClientCertificateKeyStorePassword=password" +
                        "&sslTrustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=" + "path/to/trustCerts.jks" +
                        "&sslTrustCertificateKeyStorePassword=password"